# NullPointerException when using springBootTest annotation with WebEnvironment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am using `spring-boot 1.4.0.RELEASE`. Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApplicationTests { 

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

when I run this tests ( although it does nothing now), the test fail in start up due to `NullpointerException` (stack trace below)

however, if I remove `webEnvironment= WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT`, everything looks good.

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer.customizeContext(MockServerContainerContextCustomizer.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Please, explain the reason to use `webEnvironment` and `@WebAppConfiguration`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `@WebAppConfiguration` with Spring Boot 1.4's testing support.

So just delete `@WebAppConfiguration`, and then...

- if you want a mocked `WebApplicationContext` -- for example, to use `MockMvc` -- use `@SpringBootTest` with the default `webEnvironment` (which is `WebEnvironment.MOCK`).
- if you want your web application to actually be deployed in an embedded Servlet container -- for example, to test with `TestRestTemplate` -- use `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` or `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)`

Comment: Also see Spring Boot issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6795

Comment: what if i need testrestTemplate and mockMvc? with TestRestTemplate, i can't assert for status code? with mockMvc I can. but with TestRestTemplate, I can assert for response `Status status = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/health", Status.class);` which I cant with mockMvc

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `TestRestTemplate` and `MockMvc` in the same test. The former *only* works with a running server; whereas, the latter *only* works without a running server.

Comment: Of course you can assert the response's status code with `TestRestTemplate`. Just use one of the `exchange` methods and invoke `getStatusCode()` on the returned `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: It's also possible to check the `status` of Boot's `/health` endpoint with `MockMvc`. Just do this: `mockMvc.perform(get("/health")).andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));`